# Including Null values in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query which finds the average age of each person who buys a particular property type. The query returns the average age for each property type, however does not include the property type where the 'average age' field is null. How would I go about doing this?

```
SELECT round(avg(round((datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/365),0))) as 'Average Age', propertyname 
from apartment, buyer
WHERE buyer.propertyID = apartment.propID 
group by propertyname
UNION
SELECT round(avg(round((datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/365),0))) as 'Average Age', propertyname 
from house, buyer
WHERE buyer.propertyID = house.propID
group by propertyname
```

Comment: SELECT round(avg(round((datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/365),0))) as 'Average Age', propertyname 
from apartment, buyer
WHERE buyer.propertyID = apartment.propID  (+) 
group by propertyname
UNION
SELECT round(avg(round((datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/365),0))) as 'Average Age', propertyname 
from house, buyer
WHERE buyer.propertyID = house.propID (+)
group by propertyname    -- try this

Comment: running that gives me an error : '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') group by propertyname UNION SELECT round(avg(round((datediff(now(),dateofbirth' at line 1', thanks anyway :)

Comment: When you type `from apartment, buyer` you are doing an INNER JOIN. Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to include results from the left table (properties in this case) with no corresponding record in the other table.

Comment: @Satya: That's Oracle syntax - to do an outer join in MySQL, you need to use the explicit (ANSI-92) join syntax.

Comment: mea culpa @MarkBannister

Comment: How do you want to treat the age, when the buyer's dateofbirth is null - as 0? There's a reason why aggregate SQL functions (such as SUM and AVG) ignore NULL values - it's because NULL is used to mean "not known".

Comment: @Satya - no problem; I don't think the issue here is due to an inner join anyway; it seems to be related to the buyer's dateofbirth being null.

Comment: the dateofbirth would be fine as 0, or 'N/A', I ideally just want a value to show, rather than ignoring the fields with null values completely

Comment: Currently, if a propertyname has no linked propertyID from the the buyer table for a particular property name, then there will be no dateofbirth for it, so will have no value, and will not appear in the results. However, I would like to have it so that if there is no date of birth, the average age is set to either N/A or 0, so that it will appear in the results. Sorry if I am not explaining this very well

Comment: Looks like it is an outer join issue after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT round(avg(round((datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/365),0))) as 'Average Age', 
       propertyname 
from apartment
LEFT JOIN buyer ON buyer.propertyID = apartment.propID 
group by propertyname
UNION ALL
SELECT round(avg(round((datediff(now(),dateofbirth)/365),0))) as 'Average Age', 
       propertyname 
from house
LEFT JOIN buyer ON buyer.propertyID = house.propID
group by propertyname
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much for the help, new to SQL and couldn't quite figure this one out